# Graphviz: write result to file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graphviz

I have dataframe

```
ID  domain  search_term
111 vk.com  вконтакте
111 twitter.com фэйсбук
111 facebook.com    твиттер
222 avito.ru    купить машину
222 vk.com  вконтакте
333 twitter.com твиттер
333 apple.com   купить айфон
333 rbk.ru  новости
```

I try to create chain with nodes and write it to file. I use

```
domains = df['domain'].values.tolist()
search_terms = df['search_term'].values.tolist()
ids = df['ID'].values.tolist()
f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
f.attr('node', shape='circle')
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(ids, domains, search_terms)):
    if ids[i] == ids[i - 1]:
        f.edge(domains[i - 1], domains[i], label=search_terms[i])
f.view()
```

It returns [image: this file]
But I want to save it to file, like number of `ID`. I need to get file `111, 222, 333`.
I try

```
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(ids, domains, search_terms)):
if ids[i] == ids[i - 1]:
    f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
    f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
    f.attr('node', shape='circle')
    f.edge(domains[i - 1], domains[i], label=search_terms[i])
    f.render(filename=str(id))
```

But It works wrong. It should return to `111` and `333` chain with 3 nodes, but in file I get chains with 2 nodes to `111` and `333`. This file to `111`:
[image: result]
What I do wrong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put `f = Digraph(...)` and `f.render(...)` inside the `if-statement`. The code inside the `if-statement` should get executed once for every edge. You do not want to create a new `Digraph` and render it for every edge.

So instead, you could use `df.groupby` to have Pandas identify the rows with the same `ID`. Then call `f = Digraph(...)` and `f.render(...)` once for every group:

```
for id_key, group in df.groupby('ID'):
    f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
    f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
    f.attr('node', shape='circle')
    for i in range(len(group)-1):
        f.edge(group['domain'].iloc[i], group['domain'].iloc[i+1], 
               label=group['search_term'].iloc[i+1])
    f.render(filename=str(id_key))
```

Comment: it returns error to this string `f.edge(group['domain'][i], group['domain'][i+1], label=group['search_term'][i+1])` `KeyError: 0L`

Comment: My mistake. I left out the `iloc`s: Use `group['domain'].iloc[i]` instead of `group['domain'][i]`. `iloc` uses positional (ordinal) indexing. Without the `iloc`, the indexing is label-based.